# Can't start Mongoid with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

I'm trying to get started with Mongoid in a Sinatra app, but it looks like I'm running into dependency issues. If it helps, I'm on a Macbook Pro using RVM and running Ruby 1.9.3.

Here are the errors I'm getting after running $ ruby config.ru:

```
/Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate mongoid-3.0.23, because activemodel-4.0.0 conflicts with activemodel (~> 3.1) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/Penumbra/penumbra.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from config.ru:2:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help?

Here are the files involved:

mongoid.yml:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: mongoid
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

config.ru:

```
require 'sinatra'
require './penumbra'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
source :rubyforge

# Thin Server
gem 'thin'

# Sinatra
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib', :require => 'sinatra/multi_route'
gem 'sinatra-partial', :require => 'sinatra/partial'
gem 'sinatra-reloader'

# MongoDB
gem "mongoid"

# Shopify
gem 'shopify_api'
```

penumbra.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'shopify_api'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongoid'

require 'json'
require "sinatra/reloader" if development?

Mongoid.load!("./mongoid.yml", :production)

def isactivepage(link_name)
    if (link_name == @page_name)
        return ' activelink'
    else return ''
    end
end

get '/' do
    @page_name = "Home"
    erb :"pages/index"
end

get '/about' do
    @page_name = "About"
    erb :"pages/about"
end
```

After running $ bundle exec rackup:

```
/Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mongoid-1.0.6/lib/mongoid.rb:68:in `method_missing': undefined method `load!' for #<Mongoid::Config:0x007fc0838cb1d0> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/duncanmalashock/Penumbra/penumbra.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/Penumbra/config.ru:2:in `require'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/Penumbra/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/Penumbra/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/Penumbra/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `Gemfile`, but you’re not starting your app using Bundler, and that’s why you have the conflict.

The current version of `shopify_api` (3.0.3) has a dependency on `activemodel` via `activeresource` with the [version requirements set to `>=3.0.0`](http://rubygems.org/gems/shopify_api/versions/3.0.3). On your system you have Rails 4 installed, so `activemodel` 4.0 is loaded.

The current version of `mongoid` also has a dependency on `activemodel`, but this time the [version requirement is `~> 3.2`](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid/versions/3.1.4).

These two version requirements are not compatible, so you get the error `activemodel-4.0.0 conflicts with activemodel (~> 3.1)`.

To fix it, simply use Bundler to start your app. You say you are running with `$ ruby config.ru` but this isn’t the correct way to use a `config.ru` (you would get errors later even if you fixed your dependency issues). You should use `rackup`. In this case you should run:

```
$ bundle exec rackup
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, but running $ bundle exec rackup didn't solve the problem. I'm adding the terminal output to the end of the original question.

Comment: @DuncanMalashock that’s a different issue. You seem to be running a rather old version of mongoid (1.0.6) that doesn’t have the `load!` method. You need to update to a more recent version (`$ bundle update mongoid`, or specify a version in your `Gemfile` and re-run `bundle install`) or find the docs for the version of mongoid you’re using and update your code.

Comment: Thanks, added "~> 3.0.0" to the mongoid line in the Gemfile and ran bundler update, problem solved.